# Helm 2 in-cluster code: "context deadline exceeded"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Using Helm and Tiller 2.16, I have been trying to Ping a tiller server:

```
client := helm.NewClient(helm.Host("tiller-deploy"))
if err := client.PingTiller(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// panic: context deadline exceeded
```

I am able to use telnet on that tiller server on 44134. However that piece of code is not running properly.
tiller is running with cluster role `cluster-admin` and I am able to list the releases from the CLI. Unfortunately, as I run the code in Kubernetes, it is panicking. Do you think this is a permission issue?

Comment: What does `kubectl describe pods -n kube-system <tiller-pod>` say ? Is there anything in `events` section ? Anything relevant in `tiller pod` logs `kubectl logs -n kube-system <tiller-pod>` ? Could you run the same commands for the `client pod` ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late for you but I put it here for anyone who are facing the same issue as you.

The way I do it:

```golang
tillerHost := "tiller-deploy.kube-system:44134"
helmClient := helm.NewClient(helm.Host(tillerHost))
```

There are two important things here:

- the **port** Tiller service listens to
- the **namespace** where Tiller is deployed -> you need it if you call Tiller from another namespace